# Symfony2: Configuration Node in DateFormat

Tags: symfony, parameters

I have my Configuration file class in my Symfony Bundle and I want to set a node for a date format. I can use a normal scalar-node to set the date as text for example:

```
$rootNode
            ->children()
                ->scalarNode('base_url')
                    ->cannotBeEmpty()
                    ->defaultValue('http://example.org')
                ->end()
                ->scalarNode('date')
                ->end()
```

but is it possible to set a node like `->dateNode('date')` ? Because in my `parameters.yml`, the DateFormat is than defined. What would be the best method for doing this? THANKS!

Comment: Seems is not supported.. Check [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html#node-type) for all the available node type. Of course, you can do a custom validation (i can show you how) on valid date but it will remain a string